# Evolution (ews) send email using alias

Tags: evolution

I am using the Evolution email client on Gnome.

I own 2 domains and I set up an email account (Microsoft Office 365) with one of them and I set the second domain as an alias having all emails sent to any of the 2 domains sent to the account set up with office 365.

I logged in to the office 365 account in Evolution (using the `evolution-ews` plugin) and I want to set up the ability to send emails from evolution using the alias domain as well, something like gmail [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370).

I couldn't find the correct way to do it and would appreciate some help.

Thanks all!

Comment: Be careful with Outlook Online - they may restrict it so you can't send as an alias unless you actually have your alias configured in Online - they do this to protect from spoofing with Exchagne via Microsoft 365 plans.

Answer (score 0):

You can set aliases by clicking right button on your email address (in the pane to the left with inbox and stuff) and selecting properties. There is a textarea labeled Aliases. You can add them in format
`Display Name <email@email.com>`

You probably know this and it just do not work for your special case, but sometimes the most obvious things are the most overlooked ones.